# ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor If Else with multiple view variables not displaying spaces

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following code in a Razor View...

```
@foreach (var c in Model.customerList)
{ 
<tr>
<td>
@c.customerData.firstName @c.customerData.lastName
</td>
<td>

@if (@c.customerData.address1 != null || (@c.customerData.zip != null && @c.customerData.city != null))
{ 
    @c.customerData.address1 @c.customerData.address2 @c.customerData.city @c.customerData.state @c.customerData.zip         
}
else
{ 
    @:N/A
}

</td>

<td>
    pets
</td>

<td>
    appointments
</td>

<td>
    act
</td>
```

```
}
```

and it does display however there are no spaces between the model values in the if statement.....

the output HTML is like this.  I swear this has worked before.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<tr>
<td>
Barack Obama
</td>
<td>
1 Pennsylvania AveWashington220001                          
</td>
<td>
pets
</td>
<td>
appointments
</td>
<td>
act
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Name
</td>
<td>
N/A
</td>
<td>
pets
</td>
<td>
appointments    
</td>
<td>
act
</td>
</tr>
```

Update:

Fixed with:

```
@if (@c.customerData.address1 != null || (@c.customerData.zip != null && @c.customerData.city != null))
{ 
<td>
@c.customerData.address1 @c.customerData.address2 @c.customerData.city @c.customerData.state @c.customerData.zip         
<td>

}
else
{ 
<td>

N/A
</td>

}
```

Comment: I'd better use <br />.
Write every Razor expression in a new line, and it should work.

Comment: *"there are no spaces between the model values "* Can you explain what this means a bit more? Can you show current sample output vs correct sample output?

Comment: use &nbsp; to give white spaces

Comment: Lose all the @ before the c, they are not necessary and in some cases will get you in trouble.